# JdbcTemplate and dataSources: how to swap out a thread-bound connection with a different one?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, connection, datasource

I'm learning an application which is implemented with Spring. I've noticed that in the DAO class, jdbcTemplate contains a field dataSource, and in that, there are two distinct fields called resolvedDataSources and targetDataSources.

Either one of the two has three dataSources (the app talks to 3 different databases).

My questions:

1. what's the difference between resolvedDataSources and
   targetDataSources?
2. how do I make sure that only the needed connection is in use here (since three dataSources generate different connections to different
   databases)?

(Note: for the second question, I know that the connection is bound to the thread, but is it possible to swap out the bound connection with a different one?)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read our [ask] page for hints on how to improve your question. Great questions tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community

Comment: My version of JdbcTemplate (Spring 4.2.2) only has one DataSource field (in JdbcAccessor), so if you have 3 dataSources it sounds like the previous developer has extended the provided implementation to support 3. If this is the case, he should probably have created 3 instances of JdbcTemplate instead.